# Extract pointer parameter from a structure

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

In a dll library I have the function `DRV_DioReadBit`, containing the structure `PT_DioReadBit`. The C++ declaration is:

```
FEXPORT LRESULT FTYPE DRV_DioReadBit(LONG_PTR DriverHandle, LPT_DioReadBit lpDioReadBit);
```

The structure `PT_DioReadBit` contains the pointer `*state` as below (in C++):

```
 typedef struct tagPT_DioReadBit

{

    USHORT      port;

    USHORT      bit;

    USHORT far  *state;


} PT_DioReadBit, FAR * LPT_DioReadBit;
```

The `lpDioReadBit` is a pointer to the structure `PT_DioReadBit` that stores target port number `USHORT port`, bit order number `USHORT bit` and returned bit status `USHORT *state`. I set the port and the bit, then I want to read the state.

How can I convert in C#, USING DllIMPORT, the C++ function DRV_DioReadBit containing the structure PT_DioReadBit.

Comment: What should a pointer be in [tag:C#]??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A reference?

Answer (score 0):

I never really tried that, but you could probably use it in a regular way, still using pointers in C#. Yes, C# also has pointers, but you have to use them in "unsafe" mode and you have to go to your project properties in order to allow usage the unsafe mode.

Comment: Kamil, I tried this by using the following syntax, but I obtain a 4103 error when I call the function:[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public  class PT_DioReadBit
{
public ushort port;
public ushort bit;
public ushort state;
}

 
[DllImport(\" Adsapi32.dll\")]
                 
public static extern int DRV_DioReadBit(int DriverHandle,
 ref PT_DioReadBit  DioReadBit )